# How to retrieve variable from $wpdb object in Wordpress/PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have been trying to access this variable for several hours now.

It is shown in the object `$wpdb->last_result->[0]->pid`

```
 $pid   = $wpdb->last_result[0]->pid;
```

I can get one of the values (as shown above), but I need them all in an array.

I tried adding with a loop but it always errors.

I also tried `$wpdb-get_results` which is always `NULL`.

I also tried `$wpdb->get_col` which is also `NULL` no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pids = array();
  $i=0;

  $result = count($wpdb->last_result);
  while($i < $result) {    

     $pids[] = $wpdb->last_result[$i]->pid;
     $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is `$wpdb->last_result` so you could grab it and store in a local variable:

```
$lastResult = $wpdb->last_result;

foreach($lastResult as $item)
{
    echo $item->pid;
}
```

Or loop it directly from the class property:

```
foreach($wpdb->lastResult $item)
{
    echo $item->pid;
}
```

Or store the pids in an array:

```
$pids = array();

foreach($wpdb->lastResult $item)
{
    $pids[] = $item->pid;
}
```